# Twitter Access Token Storage

Tags: c#, security, twitter, oauth

This question has been asked many times but I don't find any clear answer about it.
I'm building an App with twitter access.
Of course, I get the two tokens but as I don't want to ask the user every time to authorize the App I need to store them.
**But where ? Cookie, Session, DB ??**
Can somebody help me and tell me the pros and cons with those methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long do you want to keep the access for? If it is just a single interaction, then keeping it in a session should be fine. If you want to use the cookies over a longer period of time with multiple interactions, then storing it in a DB is probably much better.

I would advise against storing them in cookies. If the user logs in from another browser or another machine, they would be prompted to authorize again. And then the tokens stored in cookies in the original browser wouldn't work. So it would be a confusing experience for the user.

Comment: The aim is to keep them for a long period of time, I think a good solution is to combine DB and cookie/session. Thanks for your answers. Any other comment/answer is welcome :)